# AngularJS Error "element.children(...).slideToggle is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

As the title says, whenever I click on an element that is supposed to have a description of what the element is, I get that error. I have tried removing the `E` in `restrict: 'E'`  and replacing it with 'A' and that didn't work. I have tried to get my function to work many ways as I can and I can't seem to get it to work. it is supposed to show the text in an element when you click on it. Could you please help me with this?

```
module.exports = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'api.html',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            //Dom manipulation
            element.on("click", function(e) {
                element.children(':last-child').slideToggle();
            })
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element.children(':last-child').slideToggle();
```

Is empty or undefined, so there is no function slideToggle for it.

Try:

```
element.children().last().slideToggle();
```

or

```
$(this).children().last().slideToggle();
```

Comment: Sweet, thank you! That did it! It is working beautifully now. :)